# Explicit Type Conversion of sub class object to super class in java

Tags: java, casting, type-conversion

Consider below code:

```
public class Test{
  public static void main(String str[]){
     B b = new B();
     A a1 = (A)b;//Explicit type conversion
     A a2 = b;
  }
}
class A{}
class B extends A{}
```

In the above code are the two line:

```
A a1 = (A)b;//Explicit type conversion
A a2 = b;
```

Equivalent? If **not** then what is the **difference between the two** and if **yes** then is there **any scenario in java** where we need to **explicitly convert a sub class object into a super class object**?

Comment: I have a scenario where I need to get the superclass java.util.Map (basic java) where I actually get its childclass which is spring.framework.LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap please see my post here : http://stackoverflow.com/q/30378061/2323234

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The explicit type casting of the reference, not the object) is redundant and some IDEs will suggest you drop it.

If you do

```
A a1 = (A)b;
```

You can still do

```
B b2 = (B) A;
```

to cast the reference back to type of B.

Note: the object is not altered in any way and is always a `B`

> there is no scenario in java where you would need it?

The only time you need an upcast is in method selection.

```
void method(Object o) { }

void method(String s) { }

method("hello");          // calls method(String)
method((Object) "hello"); // calls method(Object)
```

Comment: finally I found a scenario in which I might need to use it, thanks you so much...

Answer (score 3):

Such type conversion is also required for method selection using overloading :

```
package casting;
public class ImplicitCasting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        A a1 = new B();
        methodA(a);      // methodA called
        methodA((A)b);   // methodA called
        methodA(b);      // methodB called
    }

    public static void methodA(A a) {
        System.out.println("methodA called");
    }

    public static void methodA(B b) {
        System.out.println("methodB called");
    }
}

class A{

}

class B extends A{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

They are not equivalent in your example.

**This becomes important** in other way assignment i.e. from `A` to `B` while your object is still type `B`

e.g. consider the sequence below:

```
      A a = b;// will work
      a = (A)b;// will work
      B newB = (B)a; //will work
      B newB = a;  //will fail
```

Comment: IMO, the OP has clearly mentioned - going from subclass to superclass. Not an invalid point though.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between the two. In fact, **you don't need** to type cast explicitly `from a subclass object to a super class reference`. So, the first way is absolutely `Redundant`.

From the [JLS - Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.5): -

> 5.1.5. Widening Reference Conversion
>
> A widening reference conversion exists from any reference type S to
>   any reference type T, provided S is a subtype (§4.10) of T.
>
> Widening reference conversions never require a special action at
>   run-time and therefore never throw an exception at run-time. They
>   consist simply in regarding a reference as having some other type in a
>   manner that can be proved correct at compile time.

Explicit type casting is only required at place where it is not obvious that the reference type can store the `object`. But when you create an object of subclass and make reference of super class point to that object, then compiler never has an problem with that. Since that can always he handled at runtime.

Comment: So the first statement is redundant? there is no scenario in java where you would need it? right?

Comment: @Ankur. Exactly. a super class reference can point any of its subclass object.. Thats the whole point of Polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

> Equivalent? If not then what is the difference between the two

The only different is that one is implicit while other is explicit (which is not required), The result is equivalent. Note: The casting works on reference to the object, not on the object itself.

> is there any scenario in java where we need to explicitly convert a sub class object into a super class object?

Java supports [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), so there shouldn't be any scenario like that.

Answer (score 0):

They are both the same. This is a case of downward typecasting which is automatic.

A a1 = (A)b;//Explicit type conversion
A a2 = b;

In both cases type of a1 and a2 is A. So additional characteristics of B is anyway lost.

You will know the difference if you do upward typecasting which is not Automatic. consider following example.

Vehicle v1  = new Car();  //Right . upcasting or implicit casting

Vehicle v2= new  Vehicle();

Car c0 = v1;  // Wrong compile time error "Type Mismatch"
//Explicit or downcasting is required
Car c1 = (Car) v1 // Right. downcasting or explicit casting . v1 has a knowledge of Car due to line 1

Car c2= (Car) v2;  //Wrong Runtime exception ClassCastException because v2 has no knowledge of Car.

Bus b1 = new BMW();  //Wrong compile time error "type mismatch"

Car c3 = new BMW(); //Right. Upcasting or implicit casting

Car c4 = (BMW) v1; // Wrong Runtime exception ClassCastexception

Object o = v1;  //v1 can only be upcast to its parent
Car c5 = (Car) v1; // v1 can be downcast to Car due to line 1