# Casting to parent type -- Java

Tags: java, inheritance, casting

This rather is a verification:

Is there **any** gain in casting a child object to a parent type?

Suppose I have the two classes 
**Parent** and **Child**. **Child** is extending **Parent**.

Is there any difference in 
the code

```
Parent p = new Child();
```

and

```
Parent p = (Parent) new Child();
```

?

Would **p** behave any differently on invoking any of its 
methods or accessing any one of its members in any way?

From my end, the two are the same and casting here is redundant.

//==================================

EDIT: 
I've been looking to have control, as the developer, 
on which method to call-- the method of **Child** or **Parent**, from outside **Child**.

So, the coder will look to invoke 
the method of **Parent** regardless of 
whether that method is overridden in the subclass. That is, 
the overridden method of the subclass will be by-passed, and 
the **Parent** implementation of that method will be 
invoked on the **Child** object.

Comment: Not in Java, where all non-`private` instance methods are virtual.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Explicit Type Conversion of sub class object to super class in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843844/explicit-type-conversion-of-sub-class-object-to-super-class-in-java)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the object would behave the same regardless of the type of reference through which you call the method.

This is by design - it allows subclasses to override methods of their superclasses.

In your example, the upcast before assignment has no effect - it will happen implicitly as part of the assignment.

```
Parent p = (Parent) new Child();
```

**The caller can't force an object to ignore its method overrides.** This is a *good* thing. Otherwise, a child could never enforce its own internal invariants.

If you want to allow the caller to choose whether to call the parent method or the child method, **then your API can provide *two* methods**. Both the parent and the child can determine how to support each.

Comment: Please also see my edit. I`m looking to make Child object to run the Parent method on occasion.

Comment: @Roam So why didn't you ask about that in the first place? Don't move goalposts on existing questions, and only have one question ask about one thing.

Comment: @AndyThomas My point is, they're either moving the goalposts, or making an omnibus question. Or at least an unclear question where the actual problem is buried in an edit after expounding on another problem altogether. All are undesirable - if mildly so which is why all I'm doing is pointing the issue out to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question: this is impossible by design. There is no way to call a parent method if it is overridden by the child except from code in the child. If the child wants to allow this, you can provide another method which uses super to invoke the overridden parent method. Of course the second method would need to have a different name.

Comment: The second method may as well be defined on the parent. That said this sounds like somewhat smelly design - if the child's method changes the meaning of the parent's method, *that* should have a different name.

Comment: I guess this would be it. What i`m looking for would be tempering with encapsulation of Child. so, i gather, there`s no flexibility of any sort in there. thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

It's called Polymorphism. If the childs overrides a method there will always be the child implemetation called. No matter of what type your variable is. 
Casting is only needed for the other way around - if you want to call Child Methods on an Object where you know that its of type Child, but the Variable is declared as Partent. But its usually bad style to cast variables ( there are exceptions to that - like the equals method)

Comment: i think pretty much anyone here`s heard in one way or another what polymorphism is.