# Why can't we use child only method for array declared as parent class type, with element containing child class reference?

Tags: java, polymorphism

Having the three following classes:

Main class

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String [] args) {

    Employee emp1 = new Employee("John");
    Employee emp2 = new Employee("Mich");
    Employee emp3 = new Employee("Will");

    Boss bss1 = new Boss("Jack");

    Employee [] myEmployees = new Employee [4];

    myEmployees [0] = emp1;
    myEmployees [1] = emp2;
    myEmployees [2] = emp3;
    myEmployees [3] = bss1;

    Boss bss2 = (Boss) myEmployees [3];

    bss2.setBonus(500);

  }

}
```

Employee class (parent class)

```
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class Employee {

  private final String name;
  private String department;
  private Date hiringDate;
  private double salary;

  public Employee(String name) {

    this.name = name;
    this.department = "Finance";
    GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2017, 7, 31);
    this.hiringDate = calendar.getTime();
    this.salary = 21000;

  }

}
```

Boss class (child class)

```
public class Boss extends Employee {

  private double bonus;

  public Boss(String name) {

    super(name);
    this.bonus = 300;

  }

  public void setBonus(int bonus) {

    this.bonus = bonus;

  }

}
```

My question is as follows. Why do we need to cast myEmployees [3] to a Boss class and store its value in a Boss variable, before we are allowed to use a Boss only method?

I understand that the array myEmployees was declared as an array containing references to Employee objects, but as myEmployees can hold a Boss objects references (due to the Liskov substitution principle), the reference of myEmployees [3] is actually to a Boss object. Why the setBonus method cannot be used on myEmployees [3] directly if it's holding a reference to a Boss object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Casting to parent type -- Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17934097/casting-to-parent-type-java)

Comment: myEmployees[3] can or can not be a Boss, the compiler has no way of knowing. Consider this: `if(keybordChar == 'a') myEmployees[3] = new Boss(...); else myEmployees[3] = new Employee(...);` The type is only known at runtime (when you press a key), so you can only call methods that you know are there, regardless of the concrete object type, thus only methods defined in the Employee class.

Comment: @rhobincu Understood. Would it be accurate to say to guarantee that every instance of a subtype can be used as an instance of its supertype, the compiler considers only the static type when deciding what you can access?

Otherwise, if you could access the child methods and attributes through a parent reference, it won't be possible to use an instance of the child as an instance of the parent.

Comment: `[...]  the compiler considers only the static type when deciding what you can access [...]` this about sums it up.

Answer (score 0):

By design it's to override super class methods by sub class and not vice versa.